# Whose job is it in Flux/React to set the page title?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux

Let's say I start with the Facebook flux-chat example. There are multiple threads each with messages. I want to write code so that when I click to navigate to a different thread, I change the page title accordingly.

Who sets the page title?

- The click handler in the threads list component (unlikely)
- The action creator that gets called by the component
- A new store that I create that listens to navigation-related actions
- A new react component that doesn't actually have a DOM presence (the page title is kind of like a custom view component, right?)

Now let's say I want to go a step further and implement a blinking page title like Facebook when the user gets a new message. When a new message comes in, it comes through some web socket or AJAX response handler.

Now who sets the page title?

- This new message handler
- The action creator that gets called by the handler
- Some new store (see above)
- Some react component (see above)

But when I set the title this time, I need to know how many unread messages there are. I don't know this until the action has fired and all the stores have updated data, so it seems the first two options are out.

**Edit:**

After posting, I discovered [this gist](https://gist.github.com/proxyfabio/e7a508cd3eb05c505b54) that appears to register for a callback on the dispatcher, but isn't a store. Is this the right approach? What would you call this thing, if not a store?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The title is a part of your application state, so you need a store to keep it, say `TitleStore`. When it changes you need to apply change to the window:

```
 TitleStore.on('change', function() {
   document.title = TitleStore.getTitle();
 });
```

Or you can implement this as a React component instead. It would apply the change on mount (or use this module: https://github.com/gaearon/react-document-title).

One thing left: actions that change the store. You might be tempted to create a special action, like `SET_TITLE`, but it's absolutely wrong. Actions should be something that user does, no something that you want to happen. Instead you should use existing actions, like `LINK_CLICKED` or `THREAD_SELECTED`, etc. Other stores would react to this actions accordingly and you could use them to update title with the help of `waitFor`.

Comment: I guess you're advocating either option 3 or 4 from my original question. Either way it sounds like I should build a TitleStore that uses waitFor on other stores that make up the application state.